# spring boot thin jar does nothing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I use according to Spring documentation this Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.24.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And it generates a very thin jar with ONLY my classes and nothing else. No Manifest.mf file at all (so it's not runnable) and no ThinJarWrapper class as expected either. Does it actually need MORE settings?

Comment: whats the purpose? You are asking about settings and there is no purpose, please describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run thinPom or thinProperties task, then thinResolve task. After that in target/thin directory you can see root (include your_jar.jar and repository) and spring_wrapper.jar. You should start spring_wrapper.jar. Possible necessary command line arguments is --thin.root=target/root (your generated dependencies) --thin.archive=target/root/your_jar.jar (your thin jar) --thin.trace=true (enables tracing).

Other information can be found in [github repos](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher)

Comment: Thank you, it was not obvious at all, even now that I read it again. And even after doing that, I still need to pack for a delivery everything in the thin directory by hand... I guess I will stay with Quarkus.